# How to run sql scripts sequentially?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have three actions to execute in one stored procedure. The issue is I need to make sure actions are executed if the previous action is completed.

For example: *Action 2* must start execution after *Action 1* is completed.

Please advise me on how to implement to get the above achieve.

Codes:

Action - 1

```
UPDATE Products 
SET MarkDownPrice = price + adjustment, 
    MarkDownDate = startdate, MarkedDown = 1
FROM Products p
JOIN PriceChanges pc ON p.SKU = pc.SKU and dateprocessed is null
WHERE pc.SKU = @SKU
```

Action - 2

```
UPDATE StyleColour 
SET isDirty = 1
FROM StyleColour sc
JOIN Products p ON sc.styleID = p.merretStyleID AND sc.Colour = p.MerretColour
WHERE SKU = @SKU
```

Action - 3

```
UPDATE pricechanges 
SET dateProcessed = getdate()
WHERE SKU = @SKU and dateprocessed is null
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand -- if they're listed sequentially in the sp, how would they not execute in that order?

Comment: What do you mean by "previous action is completed"? If it's just "executed and there is no exception" - then just place all statements sequentially in stored procedure, and they will be executed sequentially.

Comment: Computers are deterministic by design.  If you execute these commands in a specific order, what makes you think they don't... execute in that specific order?  Did you try something that didn't work somehow?

Comment: Not related to your question, but action number 3 might need a closer look.  As written, if you change the price twice, the record will only show the 1st change.

Comment: @rorap In sql, you might get deadlock. In that case, some of process might be killed by sql server.  in questions, I have three update process which could be killed by sql  server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways in which you could do it.

- Using @@error variable after each statement and checking it for non zero value (which i think is not the best way to do) which means error has occured so you just return from that pointing rolling back your tranaction.
- Using Try catch.. something of sort:

  ```
  BEGIN TRY
  { sql_statement |
    statement_block }
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
  { sql_statement |
    statement_block }
  END CATCH
  ```

  if you catch any error, just return from that point by rolling back the transaction.

Comment: Thanks, Almas.   If I use try catch block in the sql script, if action 1 has thrown an error while updating row in sql, will that process go into catch block ?

Comment: yes it will goto catch block and you could do further processing say may be return from there by rolling back transaction?